# tkplot on mac freezes

Tags: r, macos, igraph, tkplot

I am running igraph on RStudio (version  1.0.143) on a Mac (OS Version Sierra)  R version 3.3.3 Another Canoe.

tkplot does not show any windows and freezes when invoked.Only action possible is to force quit RStudio.  Same code works fine on my ubuntu workstation. What should I install/check to solve this problem?

Thanks.